# Load byte offset confusion

Tags: assembly, mips

When this code runs, 4 is stored in `$t2`. In my thinking, though, in order to load the last byte, the offset would need to be 11, as 0x04 is the 12th byte after `item`. What am I not understanding here?

```
lbu $t2, 8($t0)

.data
item:   .word 0x11111111
    .word 0xABCD0123
    .word 0x01020304
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect the number is being stored in 'little endian' format, so your integer `0x01020304` is actually represented in memory as the bytes `04,03,02,01` (in that order). The 0x04 which you thought was the last byte in the word (offset 11), is actually the first byte (offset 8).